# Angular: Assign subscription value to css property

Tags: angular

I need to set the current progress of progress bar in angular. I've tried this:

```
<progress 
  class="progress progress-xs progress-danger"
  value="100"
  max="100"
  style="width: {{(subscription$ | async)?.percent}}%">
</progress>
```

As you can see I'm trying to set:

```
style="width: {{(subscription$ | async)?.percent}}%"
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting a:

> [css] property value expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it without {{}} ?